# Создание файла в Delphi с указанным объемом без записи содержимого

Tags: delphi, файлы

Во времена Dos была такая прога balon.exe, могла создавать файлы указанного размера (правда там рандомные байты все же писались). Ясно, что и на Delphi повторить это не сложно. Вопрос: можно ли на D создать файл, заранее выделив под него объем (без записи данных)? Если "да", то рад буду примеру.

*Типа(условно)*

```
CreateFile(f,'d:\My.txt');
SetFileSize(f,1024); // 1kb
CloseFile(f);
```

Если "нет", то вообще такие способы существуют? Например - это типа как в Hyper-V\VMware при создании диска виртуалки - одна из опций - сразу выделить место (файл создается мгновенно), или например у торрент клиентов - опция - выделить место при закачке под файл (тут не уверен).

++Речь идет о Win 10 Ltsc

Comment: *Вопрос: можно ли на D создать файл, заранее выделив под него объем (без записи данных)? Если "да", то рад буду примеру.* Зависит от файловой системы. Если она поддерживает разреженные (sparse) файлы, то можно, иначе нет.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970333/how-do-you-pre-allocate-space-for-a-file-in-c-c-on-windows

Comment: 2 Akina: Речь идет о Win 10 Ltsc 1607. Думаю, да. Извините, забыл "под что" добавить.

Comment: 2 Yakov: Спасибо! Поверхностно пробежал, похоже оно (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilevaliddata?redirectedfrom=MSDN), времени нет, позже подробнее займусь. +Можно вам сделать "глаза кота из Шрека" и на Delphi этот пример дать? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот на встроенных средствах файл 8 гигабайт создаётся мгновенно:

```
 with TFileStream.Create('f:\test.y', fmCreate) do try
    Size := 8000000000;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
```

А под капотом там происходит примерно следующее:

```
  var h: THandle;
  var lw, hg: Integer;
    h := CreateFileA(PAnsiChar('f:\test.x'), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
                     FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NIL, 
                     CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if h <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then begin
      lw := 0;
      hg := 2;
      SetFilePointer(h, lw, @hg, FILE_BEGIN);
      SetEndOfFile(h);
      CloseHandle(h);
    end;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это работает! +Жаль не знаю, как и Yakov ответ защитать, хотя там тяжелее и думать надо. Ваш ответ, который практически в 1 строку можно средствами D выполнить - меня впечатлил.+А там нет подводных камней типа - на 128гб флехе файл таким образом создал 100гб, пишет готово, файл и размер вижу, флеху вытащу, а он не допишется (хотя похоже файл не физически пишется, а только в разметку диска)? +Еще вопрос - а можно где-то почитать как это работает на разных типах ф.систем (fat\fat32\ntfs)? И разделах mbr\gpt\(*nix\*synology (экзотические для D))?(Если у вас будет время написать).

Comment: Файловая система выделяет кластеры, помечает как занятые, физической записи не происходит. Работать, видимо, будет везде, где SetFilePointer(Ex) поддерживается.